# Expression of type scala.collection.Set[scala.Predef.String] doesn't conform to expected type scala.Predef.Set[scala.Predef.String]

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors

I'm relatively new to programming and am enjoying using Scala to teach myself. I've come across a problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Here is the snippet of code I'm trying to work on. All the Maps used are mutable.Map[String, Any]

```
def CreateCompleteVoterSet(): Set[String] =
```

{

```
val firstSet = concedeVoterMap.keySet.diff(voterMap.keySet)
val secondSet = emoteVoterMap.keySet.diff(voterMap.keySet)
val thirdSet = speedVoterMap.keySet.diff(voterMap.keySet)
var finalSet = voterMap.keySet ++ firstSet ++ secondSet ++ thirdSet

return finalSet
```

}

The error it gives me is: Expression of type scala.collection.Set[scala.Predef.String] doesn't conform to expected type scala.Predef.Set[scala.Predef.String]

I'm sure I could find some way to force it to the same type, possibly with toSet(), but I'm confused by what the error is. Could someone give me some insight on why the error is happening and point me in the right direction for a safe way to fix it?

Comment: I wonder if `return finalSet.toSet` will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no import for `Set`, `Set[String]` means `scala.Predef.Set` (`scala.Predef._` is imported automatically in all Scala files). This is an alias for `scala.collection.immutable.Set`. But `keySet` method of `scala.collection.mutable.Map` returns a `scala.collection.Set`, which is a supertype of `scala.collection.immutable.Set` (and of `scala.collection.mutable.Set`, which isn't really relevant to the question). Combining `scala.collection.Set`s with `++` still gives you a `scala.collection.Set`.

The simple solution would be to change the return type to `scala.collection.Set`, unless you actually require a `scala.collection.immutable.Set` for other reasons.

Comment: Ah I see now. Very well explained. I didn't realize there were two different types of Set, one being built into scala.Predef and one in scala.collection. Thanks for the quick answer!